# Turn an input string into an array so that each word can be manipulated

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, words

I am trying to create an array from an input string that is created in //PROGRAM 1 so that I can manipulate it. I'm finding lot's on how to do this once the array is created, but I need to create that array first.

I just need whatever function I need to convert the input string into an array that separates each word. I may actually have the code entered, being "var res = one.split(" ");" but I have no idea what to do next with it so that I can get and record the length of each so that I can add words to any that have more than 5 characters.

(Updated Version Below.) How do I fix the error at line 24?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project 1 – Michael Fiorello</title>
<script>
do{
    //MAIN MENU
var input = prompt ("Please enter 1, 2, 3, or exit.");{
//PROGRAM 1-Enter the string to be converted to robot speak
    if(input == "1")
     do{
         var one = prompt ("Please enter a string.");{
          if (one == "") { console.warn("You need to enter something");}
             }

         }while (one == "")//keep repeating program 1 until something is entered, aka cannot be blank.

//PROGRAM 2-Convert the string into robot speak
    else if (input == "2")
        {
          if (one == null) {console.warn ("You need to first enter a String")}
            else {console.log ("String Converted")
                var res = one.split(" ");{
                    for(i = 0, i<Arr.length, i++)
                     if(res[i].length >= 5)
                  {
                      Document.write(Arr.[i]+"-blip");
                  }
                  else{
                      Document.write(Arr.[i]+"-clang");
                  }
                }

                 }
                 }
    //Program 3 Robot Language version of the string will appear in the console
    else if (input == "3")
    {
            alert ("AWESOME!"); 
        }
    else if (input.toLowerCase() == "exit")
        {
        alert ("Thanks for using the ROBOT Language Converter!");
        }
    else 
        {
        alert ("Nope");
        console.warn("You need to enter something");
        }
    }
    }while(input.toLowerCase() != "exit");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I'm finding lot's on how to do this once the array is created, but I need to create that array first."* - Yes, and `.split()` (which you've mentioned) is the way to create the array. Your `res` *is* an array of strings, where each element is one word. `res.length` tells you how many words you have. `res[0].length` tells you the length of the first word. So given you said you have found lots on what to do next, what is the question?

Comment: Yeah, split is already doing it. Not sure what you're actually looking for? Know after splitting though you'll have to replace each element in the array to have only chars ie 'last.'.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '') to get the length of the word without things like commas and full stops.

Comment: I'm looking to split an entered sentence and then check the length of each individual word. If it's less than 5 I need to add the word clang. If its 5 or more in length I need to add blip. Then in the next program I need to output the sentence with blip and clang added

Comment: So in the end if I entered "I hate working." It will turn into "I clang hate clang working blip."

Comment: What do I do to actually manipulate the values is basically the question.

Comment: Basically if the string entered is “The quick brown fox” and I convert it into an array of [00] The [01] quick [02] brown [03] fox. How do I call that array and turn it into an array of [00] The-clang [01] quick-blip [02] brown-blip [03] fox-clang" so that I can then call it in the console for the 3rd part.

Answer (score 0):

That's how to split a string in javascript

```
"str".split("") // ["s","t","r"]
"first second".split(" ") // ["first","second"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split